# How is the Stack Overflow page title built?

Tags: support, title

I just realized that the page title is different from the question title. As per my little bit of experience, the page title should be the question title followed by Stack Overflow, as shown below:

*How to sort an array? - Stack Overflow*

The above page title is good for SEO purposes. I have just reviewed some questions which have different page titles, different from the question titles.

I just want to know: **How is the page title built?**

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript):    ✘
I expected:    
*How to validate email address in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow*
Actual title:    
*regex - How to validate email address in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow*

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)     ✔
I expected:    
*How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object? - Stack Overflow*
Actual title:    
*How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object? - Stack Overflow*

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery):    ✘
I expected:    
*How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery? - Stack Overflow*
Actual title:    
*javascript - How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery? - Stack Overflow*

Comment: A page title is always “⟨most popular tag⟩ - ⟨question title⟩ - Stack Overflow”, or without the tag if it’s already in the title. What are you asking here?

Comment: *The above page title is good for SEO purpose.* ... citation needed.

Comment: Why down vote ? Can someone explain ?

Comment: @Xufox That's what I wanted to know. You given the answer thanks +1. But why others down voting. What's wrong with this question

Comment: @Mr.Developer It’s unclear what you were asking. Were you proposing a new title pattern or asking what the current one is? How are you determining what follows good SEO practices, and how is that relevant to your question?

Comment: @rene Funnily enough, SEO is quoted as a reason in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71925). Don't ask me if it makes a difference, I'm no SEO expert...

Answer (score 9):

The page title is normally built as follows:

*<most popular question tag>  –  <question title>  –  Stack Overflow<sup>1</sup>*

However, if the most popular question tag, the tag listed first below the question, is already mentioned in the question title, then it is left out. This can be seen in your second example. The question title, *How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?*, already includes the most popular tag name, *JavaScript* (the comparison is done in a case insensitive manner, as tags are [all lowercase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216225)).

Sources and related questions:
1. [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72692)
2. [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71922)

______
<sub><sup>1</sup> In general, the name of the Stack Exchange site that the question was posted on, of course.</sub>